# Is there a way to limit the Applications shown in a UIDocumentInteractionController?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uidocumentinteraction, uti

I am currently displaying a UIDocumentInteractionController so that the user of my App can open a File in a different App. The controller pops up and lists the App with no problem. However, it also displays Cloud apps such as Dropbox (which I'm assuming associate themselves with nearly every valid file-type), which is quite annoying. Is there anyway that I can specify the controller to only display the App I want?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you cannot filter this list. You're not allowed to tell the user that they can't send your file to Dropbox if they want. :)

(If you have only one specific app that makes sense to send your file to, and you can control or have a partnership with that app, then you can agree on some other obscure file type to use, or communicate directly by custom URL. `UIDocumentInteractionController` is designed for the general case of allowing the user to shuttle files wherever they might need them, and cloud services can be perfectly valid places to put files of standard types.)

Comment: That's a bummer. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Can you be more specific with *or communicate directly by custom URL*? You can use the custom URL scheme to bring another app in the foreground, but for the transport of the data you again have to use `UIDocumentInteractionController`. How does the custom URL scheme help that only a certain app is allowed to open the file?