# UIDocumentInteractionController's Open In feature?

Tags: ios

How to specify a certain 'white' list of apps available for UIDocumentInteractionController's Open In feature? 
I could not find anything in UIDocumentInteractionController docs about it.

Comment: what do you mean by "white list"?

Comment: By 'white list' I mean a list of apps that are allowed to be presented in 'Open in' list. For instance, my app works with PDF files and I use UIDocumentInteractionController's 'Open in' feature so files can be opened in other apps but I want to limit 'Open in' apps list for security reasons. Say I only allow users to open PDF files from my app in certain apps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. UIDocumentInteraction Controller will not allow you to limit the user from deciding how to open your document.

Refer to: [Is there a way to limit the Applications shown in a UIDocumentInteractionController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11977635/is-there-a-way-to-limit-the-applications-shown-in-a-uidocumentinteractioncontrol)

The only exception is in iOS 7, you can limit managed/non-managed apps to be on the "Open in" feature for managed and supervised devices.