# Sharing image to Whatsapp & Facebook

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller, whatsapp, uidocumentinteraction

I'm already able to share photos to Whatsapp but the way I do this is by providing Whatsapp option in a `UIActivityViewController` and then showing a `UIDocumentInteractionController`.

From this `UIDocumentInteractionController`, I choose the Whatsapp option which redirects the user to Whatsapp and enables him to share the photo.

So far my code is like this:

```
if ([activityType isEqualToString:@"whatsappSharing"]) {
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"whatsapp://app"]]) {
        NSString *savePath  = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/whatsAppTmp.wai"];

        [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(finalImage, 1.0) writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES];

        weakDocumentInteraction = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:savePath]];
        weakDocumentInteraction.UTI = @"net.whatsapp.image";
        weakDocumentInteraction.delegate = weakSelf;

        [weakDocumentInteraction presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:weakSelf.view animated:YES];
    }
}
```

I want to be able to select the option from a `UIActivityViewController` and directly show Whatsapp.

Is there a way to jump this second part of presenting the `UIDocumentInteractionController` and selecting the Whatsapp app option programmatically?

Currently, the user has to select the Whatsapp option twice in order to share the image.

PS: I'm using `UIActivityViewController` because I'm using other activities too.

Comment: what "other activities" are you providing that forces you to use `UIActivityController`?

Comment: actually I would only want facebook and save to album, is there a way to do this using only document interaction controller?

Comment: apparently there is not : [_see similar question_](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11977635/2857130)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So basically, you want to share an image via Facebook or Whatsapp, plus provide an option to save the image.

Well... Lets break this down slowly for the 2 quickest ways.

---

## **Facebook + Whatsapp**

### Via `UIActivityViewController`

If you share image via **`UIActivityViewController`** then in order to provide Whatsapp option, you'll need to create a custom `UIActivity` <sup>([See Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12766300/2857130))</sup>.

The **problems** with this are:

1. Whatsapp has not provided a URL scheme to pass an image object (*yet*).
   *<sup>Look at [JBWhatsAppActivity](https://github.com/jberlana/JBWhatsAppActivity) if you're curious about this in general.</sup>*

### Via `UIDocumentInteractionController`

If you share image via **`UIDocumentInteractionController`** then in order to provide the Facebook option, you'll need to specify the UTI as `public.image`.

The **problems** with this are:

1. The `public.image` UTI will populate your `UIDocumentInteractionController` with alot more options than just Facebook and Whatsapp.
2. For `Save` option, rather than

   - Using `-presentOpenInMenuFromRect:inView:animated:` method that displays only apps that open this file type...
   - You will need to use `-presentOptionsMenuFromRect:inView:animated:` method in order to show the option `Save to Album`. **But** this will include other options such as `Mail` etc.

### Summary:

If you use only `UIDocumentInteractionController` then you should accept the fact that you cannot show *just* Facebook + Whatsapp + Save (*due to the reasons mentioned above*)

If you use `UIActivityViewController` and don't want to create a custom `UIActivity` for Whatsapp, then you're stuck **but**... if you decide to use a custom `UIActivity` then you're still stuck because there's no provision to share an image object with Whatsapp using `UIActivityViewController`.

### Conclusion:

There doesn't seem to be any easy way to have *just* Facebook + Whatsapp + Save option.

The thing that complicates it is Whatsapp which forces you to use `UIDocumentInteractionController` which seems like the only way to share an image on Whatsapp (*currently*) **and** due to it's limited URL scheme, there's no point providing it in `UIActivityViewController`.

Furthermore, using `UIDocumentInteractionController` in turns leads you to provide more options than you would want.

Honestly, this looks pretty bleak right now.

Comment: So I will leave the app just as it is, it works fine sharing for whatsapp, but not the way I wanted. Anyway, thanks for solving my doubt!

Comment: @LucasDomene : you're welcome :) well... right now i see no other way around it so you're better off the way you are.

Comment: Looks like this is a combination of both solutions : https://github.com/mvarie/MMMWhatsAppActivity

Answer (score 1):

Well, if I understand the question in a proper way, there is an option to share it easily via 1 `UIDocumentInteractionController`, please review my old question & answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20887254/849616.