# Combine UIDocumentInteractionController with UIActivityController to share on Instagram, Facebook, to mail, message and so on

Tags: ios, share, instagram, uiactivityviewcontroller, uidocumentinteraction

I need to be able to share photos on Instagram as well as also to all the options that are presented with `UIActivityViewController` - Facebook, Twitter, mail, etc. I manage to share to Instagram with `UIDocumentInteractionController`, but need to have all the options at one place. I added custom `UIActivity` to the `UIActivityViewController` activities, but don't know how to proceed directly to Instagram from there. Now it just options similar menu with the Instagram option, because I present a `UIDocumentInteractionController`. Is there a way to have all options at one menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to: [Sharing image to Whatsapp & Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921990/sharing-image-to-whatsapp-facebook) accepted response.

It looks that this option is actually provided out of the box for       `UIDocumentInteractionController`, but I was presenting the controller wrongly. The correct way to display all options is to use: `-presentOptionsMenuFromRect:inView:animated:` instead of `-presentOpenInMenuFromRect:inView:animated:`
The `UIDocumentInteractionController` does not allow to omit some of the options like `UIActivityViewController`does, but I need to have Instagram alongside the other options, so this is the way to go.
The code I use:

```
NSString *documentDirectory=[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
NSString *saveImagePath=[documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyImage.png"];
NSData *imageData=UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageToUse);
[imageData writeToFile:saveImagePath atomically:YES];
NSURL *imageURL=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:saveImagePath];
docIntController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:imageURL];
docIntController.delegate = self;
[docIntController presentOptionsMenuFromRect:CGRectMake(1, 1, 1, 1) inView:self.view animated:YES];
```