# How to share text and image to whatsapp in objective c with UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, sharing, whatsapp

I want to share text file and image to Whatsapp through `UIActivityViewController` but it shows this error:

```
This item cannot be shared. Please select a different item.
```

I tried all the methods provided in StackOverflow, but its not working.

Comment: Could you please show us what you tried ?

Comment: objectsToShare =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:abt,name,address,eventdate,fromtoTime,nil];UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];NSArray*excludeActivities=@[UIActivityTypeAirDrop,UIActivityTypePostToFacebook,UIActivityTypePrint,UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList, UIActivityTypePostToFlickr, UIActivityTypePostToVimeo]; [controller setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed)
     { if (completed) { }else { } }];

Comment: i had passed a array in uiactivityViewController

Comment: you can find similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921990/sharing-image-to-whatsapp-facebook Hope this Helps!

Comment: ya i too had tried same thing but it didnt worked for me